# Making a button with vector graphics in content

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I am pretty new with WPF design (and design in general), and I need help with one task.

I have a style for a button that contains some data in a Path, which draws an icon on it (basically simple add new icon). Now I would like to make a copy icon out of it.

I could not find a way to manipulate with Path I have in Blend, so what I had in mind was:

1) Copy Path data so we can draw two icons (to have two Path objects in Content)
2) Shift first a little to the left and top
3) Shift second a little to the right and bottom
4) Make second one overlap first one

This is what I did:
Since we cannot have two elements set for Content, I have added one Grid element, and inside I copied Path element twice. Then I repositioned both path to simulate duplicate data.

```
<Setter Property="Content">
    <Setter.Value>
    <Grid>
            <Path Data="..." Margin="10" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{StaticResource IconBrush}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.4">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform />
                <SkewTransform />
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                <TranslateTransform />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
    <Path Data="..." Margin="10" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{StaticResource IconBrush}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.6">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform />
                <SkewTransform />
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                <TranslateTransform />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>                                 
    </Grid>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Problem: I do not get overlap with second icon (basically everything is transparent. That means that I probsably need to delete some points on first icon, but I could not achieve that in Blend?

Can anyone share some light how to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what your icons should look like, but the following XAML will display two overlapping plus signs using the same `Path` data for both, but with a simple `TranslateTransform` to offset the second one.

```
    <Grid>
        <Path Fill="#FF008000" >
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry Figures="m 30 25.362188 0 30.000001 -30 0 0 20 30 0 0 29.999991 20 0 0 -29.999991 30 0 0 -20 -30 0 0 -30.000001 -20 0 z" FillRule="nonzero"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="#FF92D050" >
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry Figures="m 30 25.362188 0 30.000001 -30 0 0 20 30 0 0 29.999991 20 0 0 -29.999991 30 0 0 -20 -30 0 0 -30.000001 -20 0 z" FillRule="nonzero"/>
            </Path.Data>
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="25" Y="-25"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
```

I would recommend not putting margins or 'Stretch' properties in your actual path objects.  Take care of that in the Grid container they are in, or a containing Viewbox if you need to scale them up or down.

**EDIT**

If you are actually using the `Fill` property of the `Path` object to draw the icon geometry, as with a `VisualBrush` object, instead of the `Path.Data`, then you don't want to use a `Path` in the first place.  Just use two `Rectangle` objects, with your 'IconBrush' Fill in the grid and do the `TranslateTransform` on one of them so that they overlap to the desired amount.  Remember that with XAML, the object that appears last in the listing is rendered on top.

**EDIT 2**

```
    <Grid>
        <Path Fill="#FFFFFFFF">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry Figures="m 13.123027 65.796864 0 81.448876 133.750213 0 0 -133.778725 -67.192062 0 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="#FFB3B3B3">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M 79.624708 0.36218262 0 62.950511 l 0 97.411669 160 0 0 -159.99999738 -80.375292 0 z m 2.28303 16.89635038 61.172792 0 0 126.207297 -126.161061 0 0 -76.829978 0.187646 -0.156158 64.800623 0 0 -49.221161 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="#FFFFFFFF">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry Figures="m 13.123027 65.796864 0 81.448876 133.750213 0 0 -133.778725 -67.192062 0 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
            </Path.Data>
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="30" Y="30"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="#FFB3B3B3">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M 79.624708 0.36218262 0 62.950511 l 0 97.411669 160 0 0 -159.99999738 -80.375292 0 z m 2.28303 16.89635038 61.172792 0 0 126.207297 -126.161061 0 0 -76.829978 0.187646 -0.156158 64.800623 0 0 -49.221161 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
            </Path.Data>
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="30" Y="30"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
```

The above XAML is probably way too big for your needs.  You can just put the whole grid in a `Viewbox` and then set the `Height` and `Width` properties of the `Viewbox` to get it to the size you need.

---

---

**EDIT 3**

Custom button style:

```
<Style x:Key="btnCustom" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Viewbox>
                <Grid Margin="0,0,30,30">
                    <Path Fill="#FFFFFFFF">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="m 13.123027 65.796864 0 81.448876 133.750213 0 0 -133.778725 -67.192062 0 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Path Fill="#FFB3B3B3">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="M 79.624708 0.36218262 0 62.950511 l 0 97.411669 160 0 0 -159.99999738 -80.375292 0 z m 2.28303 16.89635038 61.172792 0 0 126.207297 -126.161061 0 0 -76.829978 0.187646 -0.156158 64.800623 0 0 -49.221161 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                    </Path>
                    <Path Fill="#FFFFFFFF">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="m 13.123027 65.796864 0 81.448876 133.750213 0 0 -133.778725 -67.192062 0 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="30" Y="30"/>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                    <Path Fill="#FFB3B3B3">
                        <Path.Data>
                            <PathGeometry Figures="M 79.624708 0.36218262 0 62.950511 l 0 97.411669 160 0 0 -159.99999738 -80.375292 0 z m 2.28303 16.89635038 61.172792 0 0 126.207297 -126.161061 0 0 -76.829978 0.187646 -0.156158 64.800623 0 0 -49.221161 z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                        </Path.Data>
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="30" Y="30"/>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Button implementation:

```
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource btnCustom}"
            Height="30" Width="100"/>
```

What it looks like in the WPF Window:

[image]

Comment: Hi Stewbob. Your code is now facing the same problem as mine. The parts of the upper icon that are bellow the second icon should not be visible (in reality, you can not see something that is below another thing). My copy icon is bacically similar to a copy icon in Visual studio. I didnt not put the data points, since the first icon (new icon), that I try to duplicate and make copy icon, is the property of the company that we use controls from, and I don't want to get into any legal issues.

Comment: @Goran, I don't understand your comment.  The XAML in my post places a light green plus sign "on top of" a dark green plus sign.  That is the intent of the XAML, and that is how it appears on-screen.  If you want to switch which Path object is "on top" you need to change the order that they are listed in the XAML.

Comment: Yep, in your example it places it on top, since you are using geometry forms. The original Path that I have uses what I believe is array of points, so there is no "form". When I change the order of paths, it makes no difference. Here is a link to show you visually how it looks. https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=F80033B5ECD8347C!140&authkey=!APGPszc9i3_m_Go

Comment: A picture truly is worth a thousand words.  I understand now.  Your original icon has no fill where the 'white paper' is.  You basically need new geometry that adds a white fill inside the gray borders.  See my edit for how that would look.

Comment: Hi Stewbob, I am still having problems. When I paste your code inside a button style, and create one button on UserControl in xaml, it shows correctly. However, when I set Width and height of the button, the content is not being resized, just cropped. WHy is this happening?

Comment: Wrapping the Grid in a Viewbox will do the trick.  See EDIT 3.

Comment: :) I am ashamed to admit that I have never heard of ViewBox, altough I have watched / read tons of materials. Now its working, thanks for all the help.